# Validar 2 campos en javascrip

Tags: javascript

MUY buenas tardes, amigos, en esta oportunidad me pidieron validar 2 `input` tipo fecha, LA CUESTIÓN ES, QUE SI UN INPUT TIENE VALORES EL SEGUNDO INPUT SEA OBLIGATORIO, AL IGUAL SI EL SEGUNDO INPUT TIENE VALORES EL PRIMERO SEA OBLIGATORIO, PERO SI NINGUNO TIENE VALORES QUE LA FUNCIÓN CONTINÚE NORMAL, es decir que solo sea obligatorio el llenado si uno de los 2 esta con datos. les dejo el código por si alguien me puede ayudar por favor.
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=hh, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        
<script src="validartexto.js"></script>
    <h1>campos de texto</h1>

    <form action="">
      <div>
        <label for="novacio"> fecha 1 </label>
        <input type="date" id="novacio" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="numero">fecha 2</label>
        <input type="date" id="numero" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="validar" onclick="validar()">  
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

codigo java escrip:

```
function validar(){

    novacio=document.getElementById("novacio").value;
    numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;

    console.log(novacio);
    console.log(numero);
    if (novacio.length==0 || numero.length==0) {
        
        alert("perfecto puedes seguir")
       
    }else  if (novacio.length !==0 || numero.length==0){

        
        alert("el campo 2 no puede estar vacio")
        
    } else{


        alert("ambos campos llenados puedes seguir");
    }
 
}
```

el problema es que cuando ingreso un dato ala  primera fecha y debe mostrar el alert que fata uno, pasa de frente al final.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los que dieron votos negativos, ¿Alguna explicación del porque?

Comment: Yo también estoy extrañado por los votos negativos... Sin embargo, no vine a comentar eso xD, vine a comentar que te recomiendo no usar mayusculas sostenidas. En internet, eso se percibe como gritar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas modificar tu condicional para que revise si: el primer input sí y el segundo input no, o el primer input no, y el segundo input sí, quedaría algo así:

```js
function validar(){

    novacio=document.getElementById("novacio").value;
    numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;

    console.log(novacio);
    console.log(numero);
    if (!novacio.length && !numero.length) {
        
        alert("perfecto puedes seguir")
       
    }else  if ((!novacio.length && numero.length) || (novacio.length && !numero.length)){
        alert("si llenas una fecha tienes que llenar la otra")
    } else{
        alert("ambos campos llenados puedes seguir");
    }
 
}
```

Además de que modifiqué un poco tus condicionales, pues un cero ya es considerado un falsey value, así que no necesitas revisar la igualdad
Y para resolver tu duda de porqué no funcionaba tu código, necesitabas un **and** ahí, no un **or**

Answer (score 1):

Yo y mi infinita vagancia... invirtiendo el orden de los if, evito escribir tanto.

```
function validar(){

    novacio=document.getElementById("novacio").value;
    numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;

    console.log(novacio);
    console.log(numero);

    if (!novacio.length && !numero.length ) {        
        alert("perfecto puedes seguir")       
    }
    else  if ( novacio.length && numero.length ) {
        alert("ambos campos llenos, puedes seguir");
    } 
    else{
        alert("si llenas una fecha tienes que llenar la otra")
    } 
}
```